# slick 'n scala : a TableQuery object without .ddl field

Tags: scala, traits, slick

using scala, slick 2.0 & eclipse I have an error I can't explain : "value ddl is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.TableQuery[SqliteSpec.this.Personnes]"

here is the code: 
I declare a trait like this :

```
trait sqlite {

val db = Database.forURL("jdbc:sqlite:rdvs.txt", driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC")

class Personnes(tag: Tag) extends Table[Rdv](tag, "RDV") {

  def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def nom = column[String]("NOM", O.NotNull)
  def prénom = column[String]("PRENOM")
  def sexe = column[Int]("SEXE")
  def télPortable = column[String]("TELPOR")
  def télBureau = column[String]("TELBUR")
  def télPrivé = column[String]("TELPRI")
  def siteRDV = column[String]("SITE")
  def typeRDV = column[String]("TYPE")
  def libelléRDV = column[String]("LIBELLE")
  def numRDV = column[String]("NUMRDV")
  def étape = column[String]("ETAPE")
  def dateRDV = column[Date]("DATE")
  def heureRDVString = column[String]("HEURE")
  def statut = column[String]("STATUT")
  def orderId = column[String]("ORDERID")

  def * = (id.?, nom, prénom, sexe, télPortable, télBureau, télPrivé,
    siteRDV, typeRDV, libelléRDV, numRDV, étape, dateRDV, heureRDVString,
    statut, orderId) <> (Rdv.tupled, Rdv.unapply _)

  } 
}
```

and here is the wrong code :

```
db.withDynSession{

        val personnes=TableQuery[Personnes]
        personnes.ddl.create 
}
```

althought I followed this official tutorial : http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/schemas.html (section DDL)

Do you know what's wrong?
thanks.

Comment: Have you imported `scala.slick.driver.JdbcDriver.simple._`?

Comment: hello; I added this import but without any success : the error remains here.

Comment: Hm, it just seems as if Scala cannot find the implicits that make `ddl` available. But I may be completely mistaken there.

Comment: I tried with "db.withSession { implicit session => ..." but with the same result.

Comment: Making `session` implicit is unrelated. I tried to reproduce your example and it compiles fine (using `import scala.slick.driver.JdbcDriver.simple._`) except for the fact that I'm missing `Rdv`.

Comment: it's very annoying because I don't see how to advance...I specify it's a play project, created by the command "play new myproject" ,and "play eclipse".maybe it's linked?

Comment: ok, got it: 1/I used this : import scala.slick.driver.SQLiteDriver.simple._, 2/ and this : db.withSession { implicit session: Session =>, and it works. it's a connection to a sqlite base, so the import must be related to sqlite. for the point 2, I don't know why it works. by the past, I succeeded in using dynamic sessions. maybe it's caused by the play nature of the project.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact that you were using SQLite, although I don't see how that relates to the compile error regarding `ddl`. Anyway, I think it would be great if you updated your own answer below and give your results, then accept your own accept, so that others can profit from your experience. Thank you!

Comment: sorry but with windows I can't edit my answer. I managed to do this on a mac but I have not the source code on this computer...

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this is useful for somebody: I had the same problem, but my mistake was importing different driver simple implicits. In my main model class had Postgres', but in my tests had H2's (in order to make in-memory integration testing). Switching to the same drivers solved the issue.

Comment: That's correct. You need to import from same driver everywhere.

Comment: What do you mean by switching to the same drivers?  I'm hitting this issue now. I'm using the Postgres driver in my source and using a h2 driver in my tests. If I have to switch to the same drivers, then I will not be able to use H2 for testing!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add the entire code, but the "edit" button is no more present under my question; here is the code:

```
package tests {

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class SqliteSpec extends Specification with sqlite {

"la base sqlite" should {

  "create a new database file" in new Sqlite_avant_chaque_test {

    todo
  }
}

class Sqlite_avant_chaque_test extends Scope {

  println("avant test")

  def abc = {
    db.withDynSession {

      val personnes = TableQuery[Personnes]
      personnes.ddl.create
    }

  }

}
}
}
```

ok, I only needed to log on; here is the working code :

```
import org.specs2.execute.AsResult
import org.specs2.runner.JUnitRunner
import scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce
import org.specs2.time.TimeConversions$longAsTime
import org.specs2.collection.BiMap
import org.specs2.control.Debug$Debuggable
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import org.specs2.internal.scalaz.TreeLoc
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import scala.xml.NodeSeq
import scala.collection.immutable.List
import org.specs2.text.LinesContent
import org.specs2.specification.Fragments
import scala.math.Numeric
import java.net.URL
import org.specs2.matcher.MatchSuccess
import scala.runtime.Nothing$
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import org.specs2.main.Arguments
import java.io.InputStream
import org.specs2.data.Sized
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.specs2.specification.Scope
import java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException
import models.sqlite
import scala.slick.lifted.TableQuery
//import scala.slick.driver.JdbcDriver.simple._
import scala.slick.driver.SQLiteDriver.simple._
import play.api.test.Helpers
import play.test.Helpers

package tests {

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class SqliteSpec extends Specification with sqlite {

sequential

"la base sqlite" should {

  "create a new database file" in new Sqlite_avant_chaque_test {

    todo
  }
}

class Sqlite_avant_chaque_test extends Scope {

  println("avant test")

  //db.withDynSession {
  db.withSession { implicit session: Session =>
    val personnes = TableQuery[Personnes]
    personnes.ddl.create
    println("avant tests, après création base")
  }

}

}
}
```